# Angularjs not being rendered to html page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So here's the deal, I was trying to learn AngularJs, since it's a must know now to properly build a front-end. However it just wouldn't work. I was following the video tutorials offered not heir site and did it all step by step but it wouldn't render.
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head ng-app = "store">
    <title>Benvenuti a TuttoUni</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../libraries/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libraries/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../script/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="StoreController as store">
        <h1> {{store.product.name}} </h1>
        <h2> ${{store.product.price}} </h2>
        <p> {{store.product.description}} </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my javascript:

```
(function() {
    var gem = {
        name: 'Dodecahedron',
        price: 2.95,
        description: '...',
    }
    var app = angular.module('store', []);

    app.controller('StoreController', function() {
        this.product = gem;
    });
})();
```

The outcome, as you can imagine is:
    {{store.product.name}}
    ${{store.product.price}} 
    {{store.product.description}}

Without actually being replaced by their values.

Comment: have you got an error in your console?

Comment: I would guess your path to Angular is incorrect - is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to place `ng-app` on `html` or `body` tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
```

Comment: Great spot! Or any parent tag :)

Comment: @FirasSafa Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head ng-app = "store">
<title>Benvenuti a TuttoUni</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../libraries/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/login.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libraries/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="store">
   <div ng-controller="StoreController">
       <h1> {{product.name}} </h1>
       <h2> ${{product.price}} </h2>
       <p> {{product.description}} </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript :

```
       (function() {
        var app = angular.module('store', []);

        app.controller('StoreController', function($scope) {
               $scope.product = {
                  name: 'Dodecahedron',
                  price: 2.95,
                  description: '...',
            };
        });
    })();
```